# ubuntu 12.04 nmcli doesn't list connections under one no-login user

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, script

I am running bacula as my backup system and I would like to run a script before some backup jobs to establish a VPN connection and access some servers that don't have public IPs.

I have configured a PPTP VPN that I can start successfully with the command

```
nmcli con up uuid xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

bacula is also the user under which the program runs filling the disk with the backups, connecting to the servers, etc. Before each job this last command is run, but the output is:

```
13-Apr 12:58 server_name-dir JobId 3577: BeforeJob: Error: Unknown connection: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

If I list the available connections under my user with

```
nmcli con list
```

I get everything as expected. But if I run this command under username "bacula":

```
sudo -H -u bacula bash -c 'nmcli con list'
```

The list comes empty. Also:

```
sudo -H -u bacula bash -c 'nmcli con up uuid xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Gives the same error message as before:

```
Error: Unknown connection: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there something I should do different? What may be wrong? Why can't bacula see the connections but my user can? Has it something to do with me being in the sudoers group? I don't run nmcli with sudo when listing connections so I don't think that is it.

Answer (score 0):

To list avaible connection (AP) using `nmcli` type :

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

To get the list of all the available network configurations:

```
nmcli connection
```

Comment: both commands return:
Error: Object 'device/connection' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'

Comment: Maybe the user don't have permission to control networking , edit the configuration file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your_vpn_config_file` change the password flags line to:
`password-flags=0` and add tow lines ; `[vpn-secrets]` and `password=YourPassword`

Comment: That is how it is configured :(

Comment: Add to username "bacula" a password `password=bacula_passwd`

Comment: on [vpn] I have user=vpn_user and in [vpn-secrets] the password, authentication via ldap